# Htaccess: trying to redirect everything to directory

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to write an htaccess rule to redirect everything to /admin unless it's /users/*

Here's what I have so far, but there's a redirect loop and I can't figure out why:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/users [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /admin [R=301,L,NC]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
    RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ /sitemap [L,P]


    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `THE_REQUEST` variable instead of `REQUEST_URI` as value of `REQUEST_URI` will change to `index.php` by your last rule and that will make this rule fire again:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/+(users|admin)[/\s?] [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ /admin [R=301,L]
```

And make sure to clear your browser cache.

Comment: This has partially worked, although it also redirects js,css,png's etc.

Comment: Of course it will because you had no such requirement to avoid redirecting cs/js/css etc. Try edited rule now.

Comment: Apologies for not specifying that, it's working now, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you used OR between those conditions:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/users$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /admin [R=301,L,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of issues, first you need to drop the OR from the first `RewriteCond` as it will try and match both rules and remove the `$` from the end of both.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/users [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /users [R=301,L,NC]
```

As its a directory, the `REQUEST_URI` will be `/users/` not `/users` and the $ is telling it that that is the end of the REQUEST_URI string making it an exact match.

Also as its a 301 redirect, some browsers may cache this redirection (Firefox did on my PC but Chrome did not) making it harder to debug.

Comment: I've just tried this in a browser which has never visited the site before and unfortunately it hasn't fixed the issue.

Comment: I've updated my question with my full htaccess so you can see if anything else may be affecting it.